# iOS - Are any assets included in the app bundle protected/encrypted when app is distributed

Tags: ios, encryption, bundle

I am including assets such as a database with semi-sensitive information that I do not wish to encrypt itself that will eventually contain up to 500K records.

What would it take for someone to be able to see files that were bundled with the app binary for distribution? Can a smart person with a jailbroken iPhone be able to crack and see the contents in the app bundle, or is the binary encrypted and all the bundle assets protected when app is distributed.

Comment: No jailbreak required. It's fairly trivial. All you need is the ipa file, unzip. Done. I have access to all of the app's resources. Nothing is encrypted or protected in any way by default.

Comment: It is not suggested way to keep sensitive information inside App bundle without encryption.

Comment: @rmaddy how does someone that did not develop the app get their hands of the ipa file, can someone do that by simply downloading the app from app store?

Comment: Prior to iTunes 12.7 you had trivial access to the ipa of any app you ever installed. It's harder now since the App Store stuff was removed from iTunes but there ways to access the ipa of apps you have installed. Assume  anyone has access to your ipa file. Act accordingly.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks reading into it. But if you can simply unpackage the ipa then you could also see everything including the source code? So the source code for big names app is out there for the grabs?

Comment: No because an ipa does not include source code. Look at the ipa of one of your apps built from Xcode so you know what is in there.

Comment: @rmaddy just did thanks, it gives me a better idea of how to proceed now and I will indeed encrypt the bundled database